# Getting results from multiple types of data

Tags: regex

I'm trying to isolate data as separate values as i get it in. I'm using Python for my code.

Values i could see is:

```
30/30
30"/32"
XXL
XS/30
XS/30"
30-30
32-32
```

Everytime there is a second value (/30, -32 etc.) i want to be able to get it in its own group, while the first value (30,XXL,XS,32) should be placed in another group.

End results being:

```
30/30 = First value "30" Second value "30"
30"/32" = First value "30" Second value "32"
XXL = First value "XXL" Second value null
XS/30 = First value "XS" Second value "30"
XS/30" = First value "XS" Second value "30"
30-30 = First value "30" Second value "30"
32-32 = First value "32" Second value "32"
```

Been trying for hours to get the regex correct, however i'm not nearly close to any correct result!

Anyone able to help me on the right track here?

EDIT:
My current regex
`(?:(?=\d+))(\d+\.?\,?\d+?|[a-zA-Z]+)`
I can isolate 30/32, but cant seem to make it grab the text variants (XXL, XS and so on)

Comment: show us your regex

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?:[^A-Za-z0-9]+([A-Za-z0-9]+))?
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/AdiEvB/1).

*Details*:

- `([A-Za-z0-9]+)` - Group 1: one or more alphanumeric chars
- `(?:[^A-Za-z0-9]+([A-Za-z0-9]+))?` - an optional group matching zero or more chars other than alphanumeric chars, and then capturing into Group 2 any one oe more alphanumeric chars.

Comment: Thank you - i knew it was simple, but i couldnt get my head around it :P

Comment: @SteffenMandrup Note the `\n` in the negated character class in the regex used inside the demo, it is used to avoid matching across lines. If you run the regex against a multiline text, you might need to use it in the final solution, `([A-Za-z0-9]+)(?:[^\nA-Za-z0-9]+([A-Za-z0-9]+))?`